# How can I Fetch data from a URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, url, urlfetch

My requirement is to get the data on a page with URL example: https://www.blogger.com/about/  I am able to do so using appscript code at compilation level in **code.gs** as shown below:

```js
function getPTtrack(linksArray){
  linksArray = `https://www.blogger.com/about/`;
  var ptTracknames = [];
  for(var sear in linksArray){
       var optoutlink= linksArray[sear].toString().search("Publish your passion");
   if(optoutlink!=-1){
  var x = linksArray[sear].replace(">.","").replace("<","").replace(">","").toString();
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(x).getContentText(); 
  var number = page.match(/<b>(.*)<\/b>/)[1];
  Logger.log(number);
  ptTracknames.push(number);
  }
  }
  console.log(ptTracknames);
  return ptTracknames;
}
```

This leads to delay in getting the output . To reduce loading time I would need to write the same code in **javascript** which can give output in run time. So if any one know which function can be used in javascript instead of the following function used in appscript.

```js
UrlFetchApp.fetch(x).getContentText();
```

I have come across various methods in stackoverflow which returns the value in JSON . I would like to get the value in text instead of a json value.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fetch returns everything you need. You can then extract the data as JSON as you mentioned, or as a string if that serves your purpose.

String:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

JSON:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: code is the same for both String and JSON ...