# How to get text from webpage by URL JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to get text from a webpage with a single line of text on it with Javascript.

The webpage is https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/ethanol/formula.

Is there a way to get the text given just the above URL in Javascript?

The code would look something like this:

```js
const STARTER = "https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/";
let chemical = "ethanol";
let type = "formula";

text = getTextFromURL(STARTER + chemical + '/' + type); // function that I want that
                                                        // returns C2H6O in this case
console.log(text); // output: C2H6O
```

Comment: See [How to use fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57425860/2181514) on how to use fetch() without async or jquery [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ - then you'll probably want [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to get the value "out" depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I Fetch data from a URL using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482334/how-can-i-fetch-data-from-a-url-using-javascript)

Comment: Your question is very vague and indicates that you should do more research and  tutorials on this topic. There's a huge amount of scraping tutorial articles on the web. Since you're interested in scraping with JS, search for "nodejs scraping tutorial". More specific technical questions are what you post on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Kalnode *get the text given just the above URL* really is *not* even slightly vague.   Sure OP should have done more research, but sometimes you just need a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could accomplish this is with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), supported by all major browsers and other JavaScript runtimes (like Node.js):

```js
fetch('https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/ethanol/formula').then(async response => {
  console.log(await response.text());
});
```

Comment: And fortunately CORS is enabled on the site. +1